# Autofill insert a special string before returning

Tags: auto-fill-mode

I use autofill in org mode to return automatically after 80 characters, the thing is that when exporting to html newlines aren't automatically added.

So I would like to know if it is possible to tell autofill (or someone else) to insert a double backslash `\\` after 80 characters.

Thank you

Comment: I think `autofill` shouldn't do that `ox-html` should.

Comment: In HTML newlines or double backslashes don't generate visible line endings. You would probably want to insert `<br>` tags there. I'd look into adding a hook to `org-export-filter-section-functions`, which seems like a good way to add whatever markup you want to the exported content.

Comment: Why do you want that?  HTML text is supposed to be filled by the browser according to available display width, except if enclosed in `pre` tags.